# Hyper-V. the mouse goes outside the virtual machine

Tags: hyper-v, hypervisor

I've been puzzling over a seemingly simple problem for two days now. There is a host w10 22h2, there is a hyper-v virtual machine w10 22h2. Everything works fine, including the mouse, but the mouse goes outside the machine. It is impossible to work in a 3D application. I've already rummaged through everything, but I can't figure out how to make sure that the mouse doesn't leave the virtual machine. Out of desperation, I tried different applications (for example, real multiple monitors and similar cursor locking tools), but it didn't work. Working with vmware, I have never encountered such a problem. I looked through the hyper v hotkeys, but nothing came out. By the way, the mouse icon says "mouse input is not redirected", I was looking for a solution to this problem, but people write that the mouse does not work at all in this case. I tried to enable/disable the integration service, extended session, but obviously nothing worked. I hope you can help me solve this problem. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: There's a checkbox "Use all my monitors" on the enhanced session settings dialog box that will do this, although using all monitors full screen for the VM might not be practical for your workflow if you switch between the host and VM; CTRL+ALT+PAUSE'ing in and out of full screen can get pretty obnoxious.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [capture real mouse input Hyper-V](https://superuser.com/questions/1559072/capture-real-mouse-input-hyper-v)

Comment: @harrymc thank you very much, friend. It worked in the full-screen mode of the virtual machine. But if I use the virtual machine in the "in window" mode, the cursor still goes beyond the limit. Do you think it is possible to solve this problem?

Comment: That's how the mouse integration is supposed to work, its not a "problem"

Comment: @essjae Well, you can put the question differently. How to make the mouse stay in the virtual machine forever, as in vmware workstation. Until I press the hotkey, the cursor always stays in the VM.

Comment: disable mouse integration, if possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/disable-vmconsolesupport?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: @essjae I tried to do what was written in the article. Due to this disconnection, it is now impossible to connect to the VM. What method do I need to connect to a VM with the disable-vm console support parameter?

Comment: enable it, Enable-VMConsoleSupport -VM $VM   I don't think you're going to be able to do what you want.  Hyper-V just isn't designed for this since the inclusion of the Integration components into Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is (based on my use of Hyper-V) entirely normal for Hyper-V (which I have) and other good virtualization Apps (like VMware which I have).

Properly set up virtual machine Apps allow the user to use the mouse (and keyboard) in guest or host just by moving the mouse.

Move your mouse into the guest and carry on.

You might wish to consider backing up guest machines, remove Hyper-V, restart and re-enable Hyper-V.  That may help. I have Hyper-V on 2 machines and no issue controlling the mouse.

=========

The other thing that occurs to me is to try a different mouse to see if a new mouse works better.

Comment: You didn't understand my problem. My mouse is running on hyper-v. The fact is that the mouse exits the virtual machine. in vmware there is a setting that allows you to lock the mouse in any case. I didn't find such a setting in hyper v.

Comment: harrymc helped me, but the problem remained if the VM is in windowed mode, and not in fullscreen

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?